# Trying to launch a projectile towards a gameobject, doesn't move!=

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm making a 2D Tower Defense game and want my towers to launch a prefab at minions. However it currently only spawns my desired prefab, but doesn't move it.

My two scripts:

```
public class Attacker : MonoBehaviour {

// Public variables
public GameObject ammoPrefab;
public float reloadTime;
public float projectileSpeed;

// Private variables
private Transform target;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider co){
    if (co.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" || co.gameObject.tag == "BlockTower") { 
        Debug.Log("Enemy tag detected");

        if(this.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && co.gameObject.tag != "Enemy"){
            Debug.Log("This is an Enemy");
            // Insert for Enemey to attack Block Towers.
        }
        if(this.gameObject.tag == "Tower" && co.gameObject.tag != "BlockTower"){
            Debug.Log("This is a Tower");
            Tower Tower = GetComponent<Tower>();
            Tower.CalculateCombatTime(reloadTime, projectileSpeed);
            Transform SendThis = co.transform;
            Tower.SetTarget(SendThis);
        }
    }
}
```

}

and

```
public class Tower : MonoBehaviour {
private Transform target;
private float fireSpeed;
private double nextFireTime;
private GameObject bullet;
private Attacker source;

// Use this for initialization
public virtual void Start () {
    source = this.GetComponent<Attacker> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
public virtual void Update () {

    if (target) {
        Debug.Log("I have a target");
        //if(nextFireTime <= Time.deltaTime)
        FireProjectile ();
    }
}
public void CalculateCombatTime(float time, float speed){
    Debug.Log("Calculate Combat Speed");
    nextFireTime = Time.time + (time * .5);
    fireSpeed = speed;
}
public void SetTarget(Transform position){
    Debug.Log("Set Target");
    target = position;
}
public void FireProjectile(){
    Debug.Log("Shoot Projectile");
    bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate (source.ammoPrefab, transform.position, source.ammoPrefab.transform.rotation);
    float speed = fireSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    bullet.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (bullet.transform.position, target.position, speed);
}
```

}

Basicly Attacker detects the object that collides with it, then if its tag is Tower it will send the information to Tower. My debug shows that every function works, even `"Debug.Log("Shoot Projectile");"` shows up.

However it doesn't move towards my target so I guess `"bullet.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (bullet.transform.position, target.position, step);"` is never being executed?

Comment: For the future, it may be better to ask game development questions on [Game Development.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). For example, people here suggest that you make a list of bullets, rather than suggesting using your `Update()` method that all instances of MonoBehaviour have. People on GD would know about Unity's subtleties and be able to give better, more specific advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vector3.MoveTowards` only moves the object once, it's just a instant displacement when the `FireProjectile` is called.

You need to create some kind of projectile script with an `Update()` function to make it move over time.

Here is an example:

```
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 TargetPosition;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, TargetPosition, speed * Time.DeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Then right after your bullet instantiation, set the target:

```
bullet.GetComponent<Projectile>().TargetPosition = target.position;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to make seeker projectiles that follow their targets, you can pass the `target.gameObject` instead of the target's position.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the position of the bullet. You are only moving when you create the bullet.

Try to make a list of bullets and use the update function to change the position.

Comment: Notice that you instantiate the bullet every time you call fireprojectile and it doen't update the created bullet.